# Get rows that no foreign keys point to

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE public.city_url
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('city_url_id_seq'::regclass),
  url text,
  city text,
  state text,
  country text,
  common_name text,
  CONSTRAINT city_url_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE public.email_account
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('email_accounts_id_seq'::regclass),
  email text,
  password text,
  total_replied integer DEFAULT 0,
  last_accessed timestamp with time zone,
  enabled boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  city_url_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT email_accounts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT email_account_city_url_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (city_url_id)
      REFERENCES public.city_url (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to come up with a query that fetches rows in the `city_url` only if there is no row in the email_account pointing to it with the `city_url_id` column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select c.*
from city_url c
where not exists (select 1
                  from email_account ea
                  where ea.city_url_id = c.id
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also this option:

```
SELECT city_url.*
FROM city_url
LEFT JOIN email_account ON email_account.city_url_id = city_url.id
WHERE email_account.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

A `NOT EXISTS` is absolutely the answer to the "... if there is no row ...".
Nonetheless it would be preferable to accomplish this by selecting then difference quantity.

Which is in principle:

```
SELECT a.*  
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.[columnX] = b.[columnY]
WHERE b.[columnY] IS NULL
```

Using the tablenames here, this would be:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM city_url c
LEFT JOIN email_account e
ON c.id = e.city_url
WHERE e.city_url IS NULL
```

Comment: preferable for what purpose? Efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `NOT IN` could be used here as well, although this might be less performant on large datasets:

```
SELECT * 
FROM city_url
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT city_url_id FROM email_account
)
```